# Export Product Error: There is a problem with the import file

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

When I try to export products via CSVI Free.

- Select export products
- Click Load
- Then press Process

Only thing is, once I do that I get this error:

> **There is a problem with the import file.**

It was working earlier today.

Here is the screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to use that button for an export?

Comment: Off topic: J!2.5 has been obsolete for a long time.

Comment: Yup. The steps was shown to me in document that was handed to me by the person that has asked me to maintain the website because the original developer/designer has moved away and doesn't have the time to maintain the website at the moment.

Comment: @isherwood do u know what I can do to fix the problem? can i do something within the log? or could i update CSVI Free and it might fix the problem?

Comment: Well, this isn't a programming question so it's rather off-topic for this site. Maybe try http://joomla.stackexchange.com,

Comment: okay @isherwood thanks